# how to OrderBy Ascending of mixed string/int column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

i m having the table like this

```
------------------------
Id  |  MergeId  | name |
------------------------
1   |   M1      | Riya |
2   |   M2      | diya |
3   |   M3      | tiya |
------------------------
```

Now i need to select table OrderBy Ascending MergeId (M1,M2,M3,M4.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `M` and then cast the value to a number. You can use a mathematical operation for that to do it implicitly

```
select * from your_table
order by substring(mergeId, 2) * 1 asc
```

or do it explicitly with

```
order by cast(substring(mergeId, 2) as unsigned) asc
```